# How can I install Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro without EFI interference?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, macbook

I have a late 2011 macbook pro, that I bought in early 2012. Is it possible to cleanly install ubuntu without the irritating EFI mac 'shell' surrounding the install, making the mac boot sound and generally slowing boot up time by 15-25 seconds?

Comment: Check out this link it discusses some of your issues https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

Answer (score 0):

[**To Avoid long EFI wait before GRUB**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=493393&page=3&p=5166788#post5166788)
If your Macbook spends 30 seconds with "white screen" before GRUB shows, try booting from your Mac OS X install disc, select language, then click Utilities- Terminal, and enter:

`bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot --legacy`

Assuming that the bootloader is on sda1, otherwise /dev/disk0s2 if it's on sda2, etc.

Credit for answer to Alaukik in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42711/how-to-install-ubuntu-as-the-single-os-on-a-macbook/42720#42720).

Answer (score -2):

You can install Ubuntu but under virtualization platform live VMware or VirtualBox this is the easy way for try Ubuntu.

But, if you want to going to install Ubuntu as a whole system I think you have to disable EFI interference like installing Ubuntu with Windows 8 installed.

Comment: So i have to install windows 8 on my macbook pro and THEN install Ubuntu just to have a clean install?? :/ isn't there any easier way to kill this annoying EFI?

Comment: No, just boot and install Ubuntu using EFI