# How to remove other OS to free space?

Tags: dual-boot, format

I have installed Ubuntu on my Mac (dual boot). I find that I've not used the Mac OS at all in the last year. I need more space now and wish to delete my Mac OS. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementary from the other answer, if you do not want to re-install ubuntu, you can again restart using the Ubuntu Live cd/usb and in try ubuntu, you can use gparted and resize your ubuntu partition to the space required. See more details in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition)

Answer (score 0):

This is the process to install ubuntu by clearing your MAC os. As you want now to free the disk space i would suggest you to create a back up disk for your Ubuntu and then do this process so that you won't loose any files.

- Insert the Ubuntu LiveCD into your Mac and Shutdown. Restart the Mac and
  hold the Option Key. When prompted select 'Try Ubuntu' .

  - Once the system is booted run Disk Utility from the dash .
  - Select your hard disk and Click on Format Disk .

  [image]

  - Now select 'No Partition' .
    [image]
  - Now Install Ubuntu normally .

> **[To Avoid long EFI wait before GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Macbook#Avoid_long_EFI_wait_before_GRUB)**
>   If your Macbook spends 30 seconds with
>   "white screen" before GRUB shows, try
>   booting from your Mac OS X install
>   disc, select language, then click
>   Utilities- Terminal, and enter:
>
> ```
> bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot --legacy
> ```
>
> Assuming that the bootloader is on   sda1, otherwise /dev/disk0s2 if it's   on sda2, etc.

SOURCE : [How to install Ubuntu as the single OS on a MacBook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42711/how-to-install-ubuntu-as-the-single-os-on-a-macbook)

Comment: He said he already has Ubuntu installed.

Comment: that's not a problem at all as he can create a back up disk temporarily and do this process.