# After installing Ubuntu in a iMac, I cannot boot my system, why?

Tags: boot, mac

After installing Ubuntu Desktop (latest version) onto my iMac (latest version) via CD and following its instruction to remove the CD and to reboot my machine won't boot. It gives me a blinking underscore at the top left hand side of my screen.

I'm in the "Try Ubuntu" phase, working with this... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

I'm eager to have my workstation functional again. I looked around here and on the web all of today with not much luck; my guess is that I have improperly set up the boot partition. I chose to remove everything during the install process in the hopes that I would be able to have a fresh machine. I'm a novice but would love to learn and appreciate any help that anyone's able to give.

Comment: Do you create a partition using the Boot Camp Assistant on the iMac?

Comment: @PetronillaEscarabajo No, during the Ubuntu installation was the first I encountered partitions, after which it was too late to use Boot Camp Assistant (or is it?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot completely replace the Mac OS X with Ubuntu.  Best course of action is to reinstall Mac OS X.  Once it is installed, you can run the Boot Camp Assistant in Utilities to partition the HD to your liking.  Keep in mind that it will ask for a Windows OS DVD. Simply follow the prompts to install.  When the Mac reboots, quickly hold down the 'option' key on your keyboard to bring up the Startup Manager.  From here, eject the Windows Disc, and put in the Ubuntu disc and select it to boot the Ubuntu disc.  Then follow the prompts as usual.  When is goes to the partition ensure that you install Ubuntu on the partition labeled BOOTCAMP.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that! When I boot to Mac OS X recovery mode it doesn't see a place to install onto; thoughts?

Comment: You can replace Mac OS X with Ubuntu. [How to install Ubuntu as the single OS on a MacBook?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42711/how-to-install-ubuntu-as-the-single-os-on-a-macbook)